# Why is inflation of layout causing text view in listview to disappear?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, layout-inflater

So I am using a custom ArrayAdapter implementation so that I have access to the toggle button inside my listview elements.

Each listview has a textview and a toggle button. I had to use a custom ArrayAdapter attached to the listview so that I could get the correct toggle button attached to the position of the listview that was clicked. Yet, each time I inflate the layout to get the view, the textview in the listview is disappearing. The values are still there, but the textview isnt. However the toggle buttons show up fine. This is the code used to inflate the layout and get the view:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_alarm_item, parent, false);
        }
        ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.alarm_status);
        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Log.d("ENABLE ALARM", Integer.toString(position));
                    enableAlarm(position);
                } else {
                    disableAlarm(position);
                }

            }
        });
        return v;
    }
```

Does something look wrong with the two lines that inflate the layout?

The layout is fine. I reverted back to the original adapter and the textview text came back up.

However, Here is the activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />


    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/alarm_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="enableAlarm"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/alarm_status"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your activity_alarm_item xml code.

Comment: The layout is fine. I reverted back to the original adapter and the textview text came back up.

Comment: Seems to be a problem when the layout is inflated. Is one of the parameters wrong, like not using the root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you are setting the text to `TextView` ? `TextView` seems to be empty. That's why it is not displaying i guess.

Either set the text to `TextView` in Xml file itself

```
android:text ="text"
```

or else inside `getView` function

```
TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
textView.setText("Text");
```

Comment: But the text comes from the database, and is set for each listview item that comes from an array attached to the adapter.

Comment: At least try to put it how @AbhishekV show, to check if the problem is here.

Comment: Actually that is a work around. I had to tweak it quite a bit though. I didn't know it would set each item.

Comment: @user10297 Text will not set to `TextView` automatically since you are using custom adapter.Inside the `getView` method, get the text from array using `position` as index and set it to `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Too long to write in a comment, I try it as an answer. I am not sure you are getting the context correctly. Personally in a custom adapter I declare the layout inflater as follow :

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)   
                getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

then I use the inflater in the `getView()` as follow

```
v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_alarm_item, parent, false);
```

Tell me if it solves your problem orelse I remove my answer.

Comment: It was worth trying. So I don't know what the problem is.